# fatal: could not parse HEAD Error When Committing

Tags: macos, git, github, bitbucket

Whenever I try to commit my work, I get this error.

```
fatal: could not parse HEAD
```

What should I do if I want to preserve my changes?

Answer (score 11):

Do you know what branch `HEAD` was supposed to point to? Was it `master`? Run `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master`.

Basically, the symbolic reference with the name `HEAD` is corrupted somehow. You (or software you ran) must have gone poking around the `.git` dir. If I were you I would check to make sure nothing else in your repo is damaged. You can verify your object database by running `git fsck`.

Comment: I think you are right I ran `git fsck` and got this: `notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch (trunk)`

Comment: @MichaelScaria: Well that's actually my fault. I said `trunk` instead of `master`, because I've been using git-svn too much lately. Try again with `git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master`. I'll update my post appropriately

Answer (score 4):

Copy the new files you recently changed to another directory, delete the git local repository in your computer, clone the repository again using 'git clone URL', move the recently changed files your copied to another back to this directory, do  git add files, git commit -m " ur msg ", and push to the remote repository using git push

Comment: this is the easiest and most robust solution

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue just now. There were changes from another repositories in my project `git changes field`. I tried to unstage them, and pushed only changes regarding the folder I want. So far, I struggled a bit for overcoming the problem with changes of other folders (deleted project folder from pc with .git, etc.). I am not sure whether I could explain the situation, but here is what helped me:

I copied the `.git` file which I **removed** with project folders from recyle bin. **Copied the file** and **pasted in the folder** of the project which I faced the problem with HEAD in commit. I saw that there were parts missing. It copied all parts that didn't match with current `.git` in the folder and showed message to skip or keep for those that already exist. I just skipped them.
It worked for me. I hope this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: It seems like you didn’t initialize git properly in your folder. Did you remember running `git init`?

Comment: Yes you are right. I forgot to `git init`. But, when I remembered I had have already been working for long hours and couldn't loose those changes.